# How can I rename how my Arduino shows up on the computer?

Tags: arduino-mega

I have a clone of a Mega 2560, and the Chinese manufacture apparently had a broken shift key. To my annoyance, whenever I connect it to my computer it reads, `arduino compatible mega 2560`. With my extreme *annoyance* with *slightly* misspelled or incorrectly capitalised English, it has been very distracting to me.

However, the reason that I'm asking this question is for more than how to rename it to be capitalised. Think of how many projects could be simplified by this! Or for many Arduinos, you can label they physically and then rename them `Arduino #1`, etc. so you can tell which port it is on using device manager. If you designed a product with Arduino, then you can even rename it to your product name.

**I would imagine that there would be an easy way to do this by reburning the firmware to the [Insert USB chip model #### here].** I've seen it done for keyboards on the Uno, so I would imagine that you could modify it somehow.

Comment: Wait, where does this name come up? If it comes up in the Computer view on Windows (not sure on a Mac), couldn't you just right click, click properties, and then rename the device?

Comment: How do you expect this to be answered when you don't state which USB chip is utilized?  With a "compatible" board it could be any of the options, and the programming process (if any) depends entirely on which one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This string is contained in the FT232 USB to UART interface chip and the manufacturer has released [the FT_PROG tool](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm) to reprogram it. But do take note of the warning on their website: "**PLEASE NOTE - The use of some of these utilities by an end user may result in a device being rendered useless**". Another word of warning is to **ensure there is only one device connected with an FTDI-chip**.

Here is a screenshot of the MProg tool:

[image]

Comment: In that link you posted they claimed they were the "Future Technology Devices International Ltd", yet their design included a VGA cable. Oops! Where do I edit this string? Is it just not visible because no device is connected?

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson For usage you'll have to read the docs for the tool and I am pretty sure the device must be attached to read the current config.